# Anyone know any way to update my BIOS on my Dell Inspiron 5458 (without using flash bios update in startup menu)

Tags: wine, dell, 16.10, bios

I bought a new AC adaptor for my laptop which powers the laptop, but does not charge the battery (wattage can not be determined)

I checked bios version, turns out the bios hasn't been updated since I bought the thing back in 2015. Go figure huh :P

I tried downloading the new .exe bios update, putting it on a flash drive, and attempting to use flash bios update in f12 startup menu. Unfortunately however, the BIOS has a guard against using this feature while having "inadequate power"

So I need a work around... Any thoughts?

(and no, the online tutorials using the -writehdrfile and using wine will not work... for whatever reason my system does not have the option)

Thanks!

Comment: Run the exe via command and this command in the end ***add /forceit***. Have you tried this method?

Comment: I have written an article regarding this topic.You can use the switch /forceit in command prompt.
https://techfuzz.net/update-your-laptops-bios-without-battery/

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to update a BIOS without a reason as per [this article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/258308/should_i_update_my_bios_.html). If you do need to, and the issue is with the battery, removing the battery entirely [might be a workaround](http://club.myce.com/f7/how-update-bios-dell-laptops-without-battery-260714/)? But be careful